My 2018 chevy cruze 1.6 gasoline jerks and doesn't accelerate over 5mph
My 2018 chevy cruze 1.4 jerks and doesn't accelerate over 5mph I changed ignition coils and still does it what do I do next

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Does the engine rev up when in park/neutral?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
